# wordpress the_permalink() breaks when wp home and site home are different

Tags: wordpress

I have a site with Wordpress installed in a subfolder. If I go with the default settings where both the entries in the WordPress Address and Site Address fields of the General Settings are the same, like `http://localhost/mysite/wordpress`, everything is fine. However, if I change Site Address to the site root (`http://localhost/mysite`), every link within WP that uses the_permalink() function fails and I get links like `http://localhost/mysite/?p=181` instead of something that works like `http://localhost/mysite/wordpress/?p=181`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Wrap inline code snippets in the ` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

After you change your site address, you have to **copy** your .htaccess and index.php files up one directory (in your case, copy them to [code]http://localhost/mysite/[/code]) then edit the index.php file to replace

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

with

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

You can find the full instructions on how to do this at http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I have an existing HTML site and I want to add WP as a blog and related pages within its own directory. Any ideas how I get the_permalink() to work correctly in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that from what you've said it's your .htaccess.

You need to add the subdirectory to the RewriteBase and RewriteRule.

So replace the following two lines in a normal WordPress SEO permalink htaccess like;

```
RewriteBase /your-subdirectory/
```

And:

```
RewriteRule . /your-subdirectory/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I'm assuming that you would also need to change the General Settings Site URL value to my site root. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, I'd just have both those site settings in the General settings set to the subdirectory path. You shouldn't have to change anything in the root, WP normally runs in the sub-directory no problem if you add it into the htaccess like I said.